# Tcl/Expect spawn of C# console application hangs under Windows 10

Tags: c#, tcl, expect

My office PC was upgraded to Windows 10 and new tool revisions installed.  My Tcl/Expect software that was working under Windows 7 no longer functions.  When I use exp_spawn to spawn a C# console program, the exp_spawn hangs.  However, the program does start because it generates output to a log file.

Prior to the upgrade, the PC was running Windows 7, Activestate Tcl 8.6, ActiveState Expect 5.43.2, Visual Studio 2012 (.Net 4).

After the upgrade, the PC is running Windows 10, ActiveState Tcl 8.6.4, 
ActiveState Expect 5.43.2, Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

Unfortunately, ActiveState website does not support downloads of the older Tcl 8.6 community edition for me to try.

I had a similar problem two years ago in 2014 when exp_spawn hung when running on Windows XP.  It was going to Windows 7 that solved the problem.  Now the problem is back with Windows 10 or some combination of the tool chain.

I can demonstrate the failure with a simple C# program that echoes user input.
I have a similar C++ echo program which works fine with TCL/Expect.  The problem seems specific to C#.

Does anyone know of a Windows 10, Visual Studio C#, TCL/Expect tool chain that works for them?

Comment: Expect on Windows uses some sort of debugging-support API to work (I was told once about it; I've forgotten the details). It sounds like there's some sort of problem with doing that on Win10, quite possibly security related. Are you running as Administrator? Is there something in the system security log? (I'm spitballing here; I most definitely don't know what the problem is. but I'm guessing from the scraps that I know and the info you've given. The problem on XP might've actually been the antivirus you were using…)

Comment: Be sure to examine the output of running the C# program. Any small change in it (comparing Win 7 and Win 10 versions) might cause mismatch in the Expect script, causing it to wait forever.